# Click on a specefic view of a ListView Item

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick

I have a ListView that displays a list of Items, each item contains multiple TextViews and ImageViews, As following:

[image]

I have some lines of code that i want to be executed when i click on my **ImageView**.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id) 
{
    ImageView del=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewDelete);
    del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            //Some Line Of Code here            
        }
    });

}
```

When I click on my **ImageView** nothing happened.

ps: I have set the attribute "clickable" to true, for my **ImageView**.

Comment: Do this in a custom ListView adapter, and make some click events. I guess you can take a look at the method getView()

Comment: I have a custom adapter with the getView method, can you the code i need to add to my getView()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle your clickListener from inside of your getView() method in your adapter

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ...
    ImageView redX = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.redX);
    redX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

             Context ctx = v.getContext();
             doSomething(ctx);
        }
    });
    ...
    return row;
}
```

The exact syntax that you need will depend on how your layout is set up but this is the overall "way" to do what you want.

Comment: That's great, i need to call inside, a method that needs to get the context, but i'm not able to do that as the getView isn't inside an Activity.

Comment: View has a `getContext()` method. You can use that context to do whatever it is that you need. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can write On-click Event in custom BaseAdapter class

`public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}` method .

You want to add OnClick event In Image view ,

```
ImageView more = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.moreImageView);
```

Than add click Event

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
more.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });

}
```